# Is there a VBA way to make Internet Explorer relinquish control of a file?

Tags: vba, ms-access, internet-explorer

We have a client website that we upload a .csv file to as needed. It would seem that the website never tells IE to take its hands off the file once the upload is complete. Quitting IE keeps the process running and so killing the process is the only way to free up the file.

Is there a programmatic(MS Access VBA) way to tell IE to stop accessing a file?

I'm not even sure where to start on the problem so any help would be appreciated

(We've told the client, it will take forever for them to fix it)

Comment: How do you accomplish the upload?

Comment: file dialog from the website

Comment: the upload is just a function of the website we dont do that part programmatically. should i clarify the question or is it a bad question to begin with?

Comment: IE only reads a file when you upload it, so it shouldn't ever lock the file for any period of time.  What are you seeing exactly which makes you think IE has locked it?

Comment: Then this is the client's web page. I suppose they have to fix their code. So 'killing the process' is by closing the web page? Yes, it is bad question because there is no code to be analyzed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is you cannot release any file with VBA if it is locked by IE from any site. If I misunderstand anything than please try to provide more detailed information regarding the issue. If the issue is with their site than I suggest you to consult the developer of the site and inform them about the issue. They can try to fix the issue by modifying their code for the site.